# Trying to add values to a 2d array in this format (inputField,currentDate,RadioButtonValue) and call them as needed...cant get this to work

Tags: javascript

I want to take the value from an input field(number) and from a radio button and store it into an array with the current date.
I then want to be able to get and display the total in a div and list all the values of the array in another div.

Here is my HTML so far:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput">
    <input name="" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" value="" type="number">
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="radiobuttons">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="type">
        <input id="radio1" name="" value="cash" type="radio">
        <label for="radio1">cash</label>
        <input id="radio2" name="" value="cheque" type="radio">
        <label for="radio2">cheque</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<button onClick="Transaction.add()">ADD</button>
<button onClick="Transaction.subtract()">SUBTRACT</button>
<div>
    <button onClick="Transaction.getTotal()">GET TOTAL!</button>
    <p id="total"></p>
</div>
<div>
    <button onClick="Transaction.list()">List</button>
    <p id="listSpace"></p>
</div>
```

and my JS:

```
function currentDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    var dateString = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth + 1 + "/" + date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2) + " " + d.getHours() + minutes
    return dateString;
}
var movements = [];

function Transaction() {
    this.amount = Number(document.getElementById("amount").value);
    this.date = currentDate();
    this.type = document.getElementById("type").value;
    this.add = function () {
        movements.push([this.amount, this.date, this.type]);
    };
    this.subtract = function () {
        movements.push([-(this.amount), this.date, this.type]);
    };
    this.getTotal = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < movements.length; i++) {
            movements[i][0].reduce(function (a, b) {
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = a + b;
            }, 0);
        }
    };
    this.list = function () {
        for (var j in movements) {
            document.getElementById("listSpace").innerHTML = movements[j]
        };
    };
}
```

I know I am probably doing many things wrong as a newbie so any help sorting this out will be appreciated!

Here is the JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/soundCat/93Jsz/

Comment: My first remark is about `Transaction.list()`. There is no use to put innerHTML and overwriting it in a loop. DId you mean to add up results then put ONCE `innerHTML = ..`? Same goes for `getTotal()`. And, did you mean `innerHTML += ..`?
Would you mind elaborating on the desired result? Possibly attach some image/state or sth?

Comment: Firstly my aim is every time the Add and subtract button is pressed, to push the value to the movements array as another array in the format [amount,currentDate,Type].  I would like for getTotal to add the numbers in the movements array and display the total once.  The aim with Transaction.list()is to list the data stored in the movements array in separate lines

Comment: You have plenty of bugs in your `currentDate()` method, like the unknown variable `minutes` and `getMonth` without `()`. Then, also add a method `getValuesFromForm()` to update the values in `this.amount` etc. Also make a valid Transaction object..

Comment: Thanks for your time EricG, I will try to fix

Comment: @EricG How would I write the getValuesFromForm() method.Also, isn't amount going to update according to the value in the field? Also, why is the Transaction object invalid?...btw sorry for bombarting you with questions

Comment: for me seems like you dont have much experience, which isn't a problem. You should try to make yourself familiar with correct syntax and very important; debugging. (I'd suggest) Use Chrome for developing, use console for viewing errors/output/state at certain moment. Next you should try to find a way to get the selected value from checkbox (I tried but no success: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaKvy) then i also did some other stuff but unfinished http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eCmEc. Maybe you want a teamviewer session idk..